# Firebase overwriting records

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

There are a lot of existing questions with this title and as I'm new to firebase and the rules of database are public can read and write the data so there is no Auth involved at this stage. This is the structure of DB:

[image]

Under questions one object starts from `okay thank you` which is the questions and in this question there are answers. Here is how I'm writing the data:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("questions").setValue(questionField.text)
    ref.child("questions").child(questionField.text!).childByAutoId().setValue(optionOneField.text)
    ref.child("questions").child(questionField.text!).childByAutoId().setValue(option2Field.text)
    ref.child("questions").child(questionField.text!).childByAutoId().setValue(option3Field.text)
```

Every time I add a new it over write the previous one and I'm unable to figure out why.

Comment: since you are referencing the root of the database with "Database.database().reference()"  ref.child("questions").setValue(questionField.text) references the same child node in questions. Consider using an an object model such as class 
called Question with a property that is an array of strings and a unique identifier such as a UUID. In this way, you can reference the child by the UUID and get the response back as an array of strings.

Comment: @Ercell0 I'm not using Auth so how can I get UUID from user?

Comment: UUID is a data Structure in Foundation. let uuid = UUID() and then you can use its .uuidString property to get a string for the value. see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid for more information.